Delay in Data store in FHIR
I'm creating QuestionnaireResponse and Observation resources tagged with patient IDs in FHIR by sequentially calling APIs (POST /fhir/QuestionnaireResponse and POST /fhir/Observation). The QuestionnaireResponse resource has the patientId tagged to it, and the Observation resource has the QuestionnaireResponse along with the patientId tagged to it. These actions are performed in two sequential API calls.
Here is the outline of the API calls:
# Create QuestionnaireResponse
POST /fhir/QuestionnaireResponse
Content-Type: application/fhir+json
{
  "resourceType": "QuestionnaireResponse",
  "status": "completed",
  "subject": {
    "reference": "Patient/12345"
  },
  ...
}

# Create Observation
POST /fhir/Observation
Content-Type: application/fhir+json
{
  "resourceType": "Observation",
  "status": "final",
  "subject": {
    "reference": "Patient/12345"
  },
  "derivedFrom": [
    {
      "reference": "QuestionnaireResponse/67890"
    }
  ],
  ...
}

As part of my application flow, I need to immediately fetch the latest Observation (that was stored recently) and show it to the user. However, retrieving the latest Observation for a patient using:
GET /fhir/Observation?subject=Patient/12345&_sort=-date&_count=1
(i.e., sorting by the effectiveDateTime field in Observation) shows a significant delay. Until at least 20 seconds have passed, whenever I call this "fetch latest Observation" API, I do not get the latest observation but the one before that.
Question:

Why is the Observation data storage taking around 20 seconds to reflect the latest changes?

Why is this happening, given that FHIR uses a PostgreSQL database?

How can I fix this issue?


Expected behavior: The latest Observation should be retrieved immediately after being created.

You're asking a specific question about a particular FHIR server (about it's implementation, not how FHIR works generally), but you don't say which one it is

I have never used an implementation using PostgreSQL. I am using Azure FHIR server and results are instant. This might be in how PostgreSQL is serializing JSON and the engine takes 20 seconds to make it available.
